# Read Objects from Map instead of database Java performance issue

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

i have the following entity :

```
    //metadata...
    public class Article{

        //properties...

      private Set<Field> fields;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "field", orphanRemoval = true)
            public Set<Field> getFields()
            {
                return this.fields;
            }

        }
```

my issue is that my service to get all Articles takes a lot of time , because each Article object has a list with 200 Fields objects, this is my code  :

```
//this service toke a lot of time, beacause it load the Object Article and it list of Fields objects
listOfArticles = service.getArticles();

//loop through listOfArticles to construct a map of fields from the list
for (Article article: listOfArticles) {

//this service construct a map of fields for each Article
Map<String, String> mapFields = service.constructMap(article);

//...some code
}
```

my idea is , in the entity Article ,i want to destroy the association with the property fields (remove the property fields), and load all the Fields objects (from the database) in a big Map (the map may contains 1M Objects) when the application startup
then  inside my loop i will read the list of fields directly from the big Map insitead of the databse. 
is this will do the trick for me and i can reduce the time of response?
is my idea a good solution to improve the performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty horrible idea, if you care about proper RDBMS usage. Do you need all the fields at once, if yes have you considered loading them eagerly? Have you identified the actual reason for slowness (possibly the lazy loading)?

Comment: you will use a lot of memory. But sure, of course you can get all the fields from the table directly with HQL: `FROM field` I guess. that will probably be faster than loading all article objects.

Comment: @JackFlamp, so can i go with this solution , load all Fields in a Map once?

Comment: @Kayaman if i changed the the loading to eagr , it will improve the performance ?

Comment: well, you don't really need my permission but like Kayaman says. It is a bad idea probably to load so many objects. Why do you need to? Hashmap takes much memory too. If possible use a list if you only need to iterate the collection. but if you need to find certain objects by key then map of course.

Comment: i will go for this proposition , because i will deploy the project in a big real server so no memory issue, Regards !

Comment: Well eager loading can help, especially if you're dealing with an N+1 situation. That doesn't mean you need to change the fetchtype (in fact, you should keep it lazy), but you can enable eager fetching where needed. The biggest problem here is you're trying to fix an issue you don't understand, with a solution that's not exactly recommended. Like I said, you should find out what causes the performance issues before you attempt to fix it. Or do what you want, just don't forget that you have been warned.

Comment: i know the issue, the service that get all Article get also theire List of object and each list may has 200 or more Object this , and the user call this service everytime, so i want to load all Fields in the Map once, then users can use it later instead of going every time to the database.

Comment: No, you don't know the issue. Have you looked at the SQL that Hibernate generates? I'm betting no, since you didn't have an idea whether lazy/eager affects this. Also, why are you getting all the articles? Is the user going to use all of them at once? Have you considered pagination? There are a lot of things you haven't explained, and one really poor solution that you decided is the best. Are asking for help or not? If you are, then don't act like you know better than people with way more experience than you have.

Comment: @Kayaman don't take it personally, we are here to share knowledge and help each other, not here to know who are more experience than other

Comment: I'm not taking it personally, I want to know if you are interested in a proper solution to your problem or not. It's clear that you're not very experienced, which is why I'm asking you: do you want to do things right or not? If the answer is no, then by all means, go with your design. If the answer is yes, explain what your system does, how those articles are used etc. You don't **want** to write bad code and bad design, do you?

Comment: who told you that i'm the developper who did this design and write this code? my mission is just to debug the code and undesrtand why the performance is poor , and propose some solutions. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use some second-level cache?

Comment: Well do you want to propose **bad** solutions? Why are you trying to fix it, when you don't seem to have the slightest clue about performance optimization? You're doing a bad job.

Answer (score 0):

Load the entire table is never a good idea, I will suggest some points to improve your performance.

- Create a pagination for your database results
- If possible, load just the the Article and show the properties in the list or somewhere you are presenting
- Just when you go to an article, load the details (fields) from this specific article
- Put the fields you have loaded in a map and when you try to access an article, verify first if you already have in the memory, if not then you go to the database.

Try to use the lazy load every time you can to improve your system performance. Remember that doing this you will probably improve your performance but in the other hand you are using more memory, maybe you could consider just use the 3 first points listed.

Comment: i know that the pagination is the best solution , but i'm in a situation where i can't use it (due to some project requirements..) , this is why i'm looking for alternative , like load All Fields once in a Map inside a bean with scope application , so all users can use the same Map, alsothe project will be deployed in a powerful Server, so i think there is no Memory Performance issues!

Comment: If you can list the Articles and just when need to access load the fields and put in the map, the performance will be even better, load all the fields at once will cause poor performance at least in the time you are loading.

Comment: "load all the fields at once will cause poor performance" , yes , but this will be in the application statrup , so load once

Comment: The comment about lazy loading is completely wrong. It doesn't use more memory, it just loads relationships lazily. It's also not a magic bullet that increases performance, in many cases it does exactly the opposite. However, it's still advantageous to mark relationships as lazy, because you can enforce eager loading for a lazy relationship, but you can't do it the other way around.

Comment: @Kayaman My comment about the memory usage is about the map, after load. The lazy load was a suggestion to increase the performance.

Comment: He already has lazy loading. What might improve performance is to eagerly load the fields as he's loading the articles, to avoid an N+1 select situation. However it's hard to say without seeing some code. Although I doubt if he really even needs **all** the articles.